# Pythonでの日本語の文字化けについて

Tags: python

以下のコードを実行すると、日本語が文字化けします。
原因を教えてください。初心者ですがよろしくお願いします！

```
message="Hello Python world!"
print(message)

message="Hello 最短距離で学ぶゼロからしっかり学ぶ　Python入門 world!"
print(message)
```

Comment: 念のため、実行環境や実行手順についての情報もあると回答のヒントになるかもしれません。(例: Windows のメモ帳で .py ファイルを作成し、コマンドプロンプトから実行 etc...)

Comment: OSはWindowsでしょうか？また文字コードはShift-JISですか、それともUTF-8ですか？